# How to keep two inline divs relative when window size changes?

Tags: css, html

I have two `div`s wrapped and inline with each other. First contains an image, the second a menu. They are flexible in dimensions as to fit the users entire screen and maintain proportions with height in mind only. Width is not a problem.

As the window size changes, the image rescales but the menu appears to have a fixed or absolute position. How can I make the second div containing the menu move in proportion to the first div with the image. Instead of a gap appearing between them or overflowing over each other in the other direction.

Thank you for any help!

```css
/*CSS*/

html, body, .parent {
  height: 100%;
  margin:0;
}

.parent {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;

}
img {
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

menu ul, li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<div class="parent">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="http://www.wallpit.com/file/127/1536x2048/crop/romantic-nature.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div id="menu"><ul>
      <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Example</a></li>
      </ul></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liam14000/sEWFc/) example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the width of "left" div.

Try this:

```
img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.left {
   width:500px;
}
```

Comment: This removes the flexible height dimensions of the image. So as the window size changes the image no longer rescales. @Gabriella

Comment: You must set its width to make it work. You can try adding these lines: img{width:100%;} .left{max-width:500px;}

Comment: Thank you, almost there. I need the image to maintain its proportions so the height and width ratio the same as it expands and contracts. Is this possible? @Gabriella

Comment: If you want same ratio based on the height, you need to use javascript to calculate its ratio, which is more complicated.